# EF sorting results without order by clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

In my asp.net mvc app, I'm using the entity framework to return a list of data. The data returned is in ascending order, even though I don't have an order by clause in my linq statement:

```
using (TNTContext tnt = new TNTContext())
    {
        var result = tnt.Wave.Include("Terminals").ToList();
    }
```

I checked sql server profiler and sure enough:

[image]

LINQ (or the entity framework I'm not sure which) is by default, ordering my results. Is there a way to turn this off?

Comment: yes, add your own `order by`

Comment: @TMcKeown I want the results to be returned in the same order they are in the database.

Comment: @broke, there is no order in database, A simple select without order by , would return records in indeterministic order.

Comment: that is not a reliable request.  The ORDER BY is dictated by the plan.  If the plan decides to use an index then you will be your results based on that, other executions will possibly use a different plan and thus a different order.  You are better off adding an ORDER BY

Comment: @Habib My LINQ statement doesn't have an order by....

Comment: What's causing the _select ... from (select ...)_ clause, a view or something in the entity model? I'm guessing what ever is causing that, is causing the two order-by's. The select ... left outer join would normally fulfill the Wave.Include("Terminals") query.

Answer (score 0):

If i am not it is doing order by because it is trying to join two tables to fetch the related data

```
var result = tnt.Wave.Include("Terminals").ToList();
```

When you say Include it will try to join Wave table with Terminals table and in case of join  query is optimized if data is ordered.